# Is there Auto refresh in Jetpack Compose viewer in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

there is a design viewer in android studio for jetpack compose but it needs to be refreshed if code changed,
it's annoying! Is there Auto-refresh in Jetpack Compose viewer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of now, it requires you to do a build explicitly. Hopefully this changes in the future..

Answer (score 1):

**Currently** jetpack compose ***does not*** support **Hot reloads** or **Auto updates**.

But there are **some properties** which can be ***Auto updated***.

**For detail info** [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70599022/4777524)

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest canary build, and it will auto refresh.
Check on AS 4.2 canary 11