# is there hot reload in Jetpack like flutter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

any idea to make android studio Jetpack compose auto refresh like Hot reload in Flutter it's annoying! Is there Auto-refresh in Jetpack Compose viewer?

Comment: No hot reload or auto preview refresh in compose 

Answer (score 5):

Right now, compose ***does not*** support **Hot reloads**.
But **Literals values can be updated directly**.

Some supported types.

***Int***

***String***

***Color***

***Dp***

***Boolean***

[image]

You can view constant literals that trigger real-time updates without the compilation step by **enabling these highlighted values**.

[image]

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#iterative-code-dev)

Answer (score 3):

When Android Studio Electric Eel becomes stable, Live Edit is enabled by default that acts as Hot Reload. [Right now its still on preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#live_edit).

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to expand on @jim-ovejera answer and let people know, that Live Edit, that acts as Hot Reload, is now stable and has it's own guide in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/iterative-development)